# How to install Midone - Vuejs 3 Admin Dashboard Template under Laravel/Inertiajs app?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

My company bought Midone - Vuejs 3 Admin Dashboard Template + HTML Version + XD Design File
( https://themeforest.net/item/midone-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/28123408 )
I try to use HTML Version, as I want to use this template in Laravel 8 app / inertia-vue3 app.

Under Midone Vue/HTML Version subdirectoty I see subdirectories :
Icewall v1.0.9
Rubick v3.1.0
Tinker v1.0.6

I try first and I read in docs Midone Vue/HTML Version/Icewall v1.0.9/Documentation/index.html in “Build Tools” section :

```
Build Tools
Learn how to configure Laravel Mix
Laravel Mix is ​​a wrapper for webpack. With Laravel Mix, we can shorten our build tools configuration and focus on the code we want to develop. You can configure Laravel Mix on the webpack.mix.js file.

                            

...
mix.js("src/js/app.js", "public/dist/js")
    .sass("src/sass/app.scss", "public/dist/css")
...
```

I have file resources/js/app.js with content :

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mixin({ methods: { route } })
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

I found file Midone Vue/HTML Version/Icewall v1.0.9/Source/src/js/app.js with content :

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | 3rd Party Libraries
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Import 3rd party library JS files.
 |
 */
import "./bootstrap";
import "./tw-starter";
import "./chart";
import "./highlight";
import "./feather";
import "./tiny-slider";
import "./tippy";
import "./datepicker";
import "./tom-select";
import "./dropzone";
import "./validation";
import "./zoom";
import "./notification";
import "./tabulator";
import "./calendar";

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Components
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Import JS components.
 |
 */
import "./maps";
import "./chat";
import "./show-modal";
import "./show-slide-over";
import "./show-dropdown";
import "./search";
import "./copy-code";
import "./show-code";
import "./side-menu";
import "./mobile-menu";
import "./side-menu-tooltip";
import "./dark-mode-switcher";
```

I suppose I need to copy content of “Midone Vue/HTML Version/Icewall v1.0.9/Source/src” subdirectory, but
not sure under which subdirectory?

In which way have I to modify my resources/js/app.js and webpack.mix.js file ?

**UPDATED BLOCK 1:**

I found at instructions how to use Midone under Laravel 8 app at
https://themeforest.net/item/midone-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/28123408/comments?page=14

starting from point :

> Please follow the steps below.

I replaced webpack.mix.js with code of this sample :

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.alias({
    "@": path.join(__dirname, "resources/app"),
    "~": path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
});

mix
    .js("resources/app/main.js", "public/dist/js")
    .vue()
    .sass("resources/app/assets/sass/app.scss", "public/dist/css")
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.js")],
    })
    .autoload({
        "cash-dom": ["cash"],
        "@popperjs/core": ["Popper"],
    })
    .browserSync({
        proxy: "midone-vue-laravel.test",
        files: ["resources/**/*.*"],
    });
```

But I got error at console buildeng npm :

```
$ npm run dev

> @ dev /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited
> npm run development


> @ development /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited
> mix

[webpack-cli] ReferenceError: path is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/webpack.mix.js:16:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at module.exports (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:11:5)
    at loadConfigByPath (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1745:27)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/master/.npm/_logs/2022-01-06T05_07_47_079Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/master/.npm/_logs/2022-01-06T05_07_47_123Z-debug.log
```

Actually I do not any path var defined in webpack.mix.js. In the article above it was not clear what path var is form...
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check UPDATED BLOCK 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding line :

```
const path = require('path'); //add this
```

fixed this issue